# Problem switch build variant with Dynamic Feature on Android Studio 3.6

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build-variant

After I upgrade Android Studio to the latest release 3.6 I faced with the problem when I switch between variants during develop app (has dynamic feature).

My Settings `flavors` for all modules (app/library/dynamic-feature):

```
flavorDimensions "default"

productFlavors {
    dev {
        isDefault.set(true)
        dimension "default"
    }
    live {
        dimension "default"
    }
    qa {
        dimension "default"
    }
}
```

Default variant (both AS3.6 and previous)

[image]

When I switched to `qa` flavor on AS 3.5.x

[image]

When I do that on AS 3.6:

[image]

Then AS show message:

`Module 'xxx' has variant 'qaDebug' selected, but the module 'dynamic-feature' depends on variant 'devDebug'`

My configuration in module `dynamic-feature` is depended on build variant. Now, it's always fallback to `dev`.

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Any suggestions are appreciated, thank you.

**UPDATE** 
This problem also happens on AS4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, I need to manually change variant for `dynamic-feature` module, then it's worked.

But any time I switch between variants, I will have to sync two times (one for first switching on app module, other for switching variant for `dynamic-feature` because I only have one module `dynamic-feature`)

Comment: I confirm, same problem here, same solution.

Comment: No solution for this, huh? I'm working on a project with 10+ dynamic modules and it is really annoying!

Comment: Same problem here. I need to manually change variant. Wait for it to sync and then do it again for my other modules. This is too tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Its not working anymore after adding build flavors. Have no idea what to do.

I had this issue, but after updating to Android Studio 4.0, Gradle 6.5 and Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0, now I don't have to manually switch my dynamic-feature modules anymore, they follow the main module.

Comment: using AGP 4.0 & Gradle Wrapper 6.1.1 I still unable to use this features. Does Gradle Wrapper 6.5 necessary to activate this feature? manually switching variant with multiple DFM sometimes leading to human error issue

Comment: update: using gradle wrapper 6.5.1 also still doesn't works

Comment: the issue reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159377709 & https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160851593